# Time complexity: input magnitude vs input size

Tags: algorithms

I would like to compute the time efficiency (or complexity) of the following algorithm.

```
Algorithm Binary(n)
count := 1;
while n > 1 do
  count++;
  n := floor(n/2);
return count
```

Now, one may say the time efficiency is O(log *n*). But since *n* is not the input size but rather the magnitude, could we say that the Algorithm is sublinear in magnitude and linear (log 2^*s* = *s* where *s* is the input size) in size?

Many thanks!